# Set Epoch timestamp in ms-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, epoch

I am trying to set the value of a particular field in MS-SQL 12 to the epoch timestamp at that moment. For now, I used a convoluted query:

```
UPDATE SOME_TABLE
    SET SOME_EPOCH_TIMESTAMP = CAST(DATEDIFF(second, '19700101', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS BIGINT) * 1000
    WHERE SOME_CONDITION > 0;
```

What is a better way of doing this via MS-SQL builtins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `DATEDIFF(s, '1970-01-01', GETUTCDATE())` is the best way.

If you want to let code clearer you can write a function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].Epoch_TIMESTAMP ()
RETURNS BIGINT 
AS BEGIN
    RETURN DATEDIFF(s, '1970-01-01', GETUTCDATE())
END
```

using would be

```
SELECT [dbo].Epoch_TIMESTAMP()
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ea3d23b7ab5f054ba6790aabe33c73aa)

Comment: @mu無 Glad to help :)